# Problems with Heroku using Ruby on rails,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, pg

I'm sorry I know that lots of people had asked similar questions but in all the different answers I've seen there were no working ones.
I'am curently following this tutorial : http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book.
Here is my app : https://github.com/melki/first_app 
Here is my Gemfile :

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"
# gem "rails"
ruby '1.9.3'
gem "heroku"
gem  'rails', '3.2.13'
group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end
```

that's a simple one...

Here are my logs from Heroku :

```
        2013-04-13T17:37:27.600820+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-13T17:37:27.600820+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-04-13T17:37:27.600820+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-04-13T17:37:28.895845+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-13T17:37:28.909457+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-13T17:47:24.873811+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-04-13T17:47:26.701802+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 37586`
2013-04-13T17:47:28.040408+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-04-13T17:47:28.039667+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32:in `read': No such file or directory - config.ru (Errno::ENOENT)
2013-04-13T17:47:28.039914+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-04-13T17:47:28.040065+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-04-13T17:47:28.039990+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-04-13T17:47:28.040166+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-04-13T17:47:28.039836+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32:in `load'
2013-04-13T17:47:28.040332+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-04-13T17:47:28.040244+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-13T17:47:29.402379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-13T17:47:29.416139+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-13T17:48:34.162437+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by melchior.toldi@gmail.com
2013-04-13T17:48:36.892769+00:00 heroku[run.2268]: Awaiting client
2013-04-13T17:48:36.892769+00:00 heroku[run.2268]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-04-13T17:48:37.791304+00:00 heroku[run.2268]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-13T17:48:40.807677+00:00 heroku[run.2268]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-13T17:48:40.842046+00:00 heroku[run.2268]: State changed from up to complete
2013-04-13T17:49:37.705672+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com fwd="82.247.99.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-13T17:49:38.049712+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com fwd="82.247.99.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-13T17:57:36.956393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 8234`
2013-04-13T17:57:34.713361+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-04-13T17:57:38.537721+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-04-13T17:57:38.537721+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-04-13T17:57:38.537721+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-04-13T17:57:38.537721+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32:in `load'
2013-04-13T17:57:38.537721+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-04-13T17:57:38.537721+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32:in `read': No such file or directory - config.ru (Errno::ENOENT)
2013-04-13T17:57:38.537721+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-13T17:57:38.537721+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-04-13T17:57:38.537721+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-04-13T17:57:39.927361+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-13T17:57:43.593400+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-13T18:07:55.320873+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-04-13T18:07:58.034529+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 4633`
2013-04-13T18:07:59.616225+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32:in `read': No such file or directory - config.ru (Errno::ENOENT)
2013-04-13T18:07:59.616225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32:in `load'
2013-04-13T18:07:59.616225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-04-13T18:07:59.616225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-04-13T18:07:59.616225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-04-13T18:07:59.616225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-04-13T18:07:59.616225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-04-13T18:07:59.616225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-04-13T18:07:59.616225+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-13T18:08:01.041217+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-13T18:08:01.026363+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-13T18:08:15.278264+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com fwd="188.167.200.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-13T18:08:16.189360+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com fwd="188.167.200.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-13T18:08:16.328385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com fwd="188.167.200.167" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-13T18:10:14.449584+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com fwd="64.237.39.250" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-13T18:18:27.461322+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-04-13T18:18:29.173061+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 33230`
2013-04-13T18:18:30.386288+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32:in `load'
2013-04-13T18:18:30.386381+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-04-13T18:18:30.386562+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-04-13T18:18:30.386957+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-04-13T18:18:30.386476+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5
.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-04-13T18:18:30.386866+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-04-13T18:18:30.386765+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-13T18:18:30.386129+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32:in `read': No such file or directory - config.ru (Errno::ENOENT)
2013-04-13T18:18:30.386674+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-04-13T18:18:31.676857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-13T18:18:31.684586+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-13T18:29:07.524843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-04-13T18:29:09.507194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 26133`
2013-04-13T18:29:11.221741+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-04-13T18:29:11.221817+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-04-13T18:29:11.221566+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32:in `load'
2013-04-13T18:29:11.221968+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-13T18:29:11.221373+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32:in `read': No such file or directory - config.ru (Errno::ENOENT)
2013-04-13T18:29:11.221892+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-04-13T18:29:11.221662+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-04-13T18:29:11.222059+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-04-13T18:29:11.222137+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-04-13T18:29:12.554083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-13T18:29:12.547227+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-13T18:29:35.422394+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com fwd="82.247.99.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-13T18:29:35.704799+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com fwd="82.247.99.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-13T18:29:39.570979+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com fwd="82.247.99.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-13T18:29:39.851899+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com fwd="82.247.99.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-13T18:39:46.195056+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-04-13T18:39:47.796625+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 34436`
2013-04-13T18:39:48.942222+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2013-04-13T18:39:48.942148+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2013-04-13T18:39:48.941907+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32:in `read': No such file or directory - config.ru (Errno::ENOENT)
2013-04-13T18:39:48.942636+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2013-04-13T18:39:50.103490+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-13T18:39:48.942560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2013-04-13T18:39:50.115132+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-04-13T18:39:48.942473+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2013-04-13T18:39:48.942070+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:32:in `load'
2013-04-13T18:39:48.942380+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2013-04-13T18:39:48.942306+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2013-04-13T18:40:30.990826+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com fwd="82.247.99.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-04-13T18:40:31.347409+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com fwd="82.247.99.235" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

When I type : Heroku ps

```
melki@melkunix:~/rails_projects/first_app$ heroku ps
=== web: `bundle exec rails server -p $PORT`
web.1: crashed 2013/04/13 18:46:03 (~ 5m ago)
```

And when I do :

> heroku run rake db:migrate

I get :

```
melki@melkunix:~/rails_projects/first_app$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.9445
rake aborted!
can't activate rails (= 2.3.14), already activated rails-3.2.13. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler- 1.3.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:224:in `block in replace_gem'
/app/config/boot.rb:60:in `load_rails_gem'
/app/config/boot.rb:54:in `load_initializer'
/app/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
/app/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
/app/config/boot.rb:114:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in     `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:589:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

And here is the app whith the error message : http://radiant-river-7942.herokuapp.com/

I stay at your disposition for any other file if that could help you.
Excuse my english.

Comment: have you executed migrations? Also try committing some code and pushing again.

Comment: what do you mean by 'executed migrations' ? @maximus if you mean `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I got :
    `Running 'rake db:migrate' attached to terminal... up, run.6348
    rake aborted!
    can't activate rails (= 2.3.14), already activated rails-3.2.13.                          Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your Gem file. delete Gemfile.lock and run bundle install and push the code and run migrations.

You have already installed rails 2 and just added rails 3 to Gem file without

```
bundle update
```

Comment: run migrations mean heroku run rake db:migrate ?

Comment: nope, still the same message when I run migrations, and the application still does'nt work. Here is the repo on github https://github.com/melki/first_app

Comment: I didn't find any migrations and models their. Have you missed to commit those files?

Comment: it's an empty project, i've just did 'rails new first_app' @maximus